# Pie Charts JS: How to set units?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i want to set units in my pie chart-pie.js. in this data sets i want to add a unit "'Rp'+data" in my pie-chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmpsM.png)

here is my code

```
// Pie Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Makassar", "Sinjae", "Bulukumba", "Gowa"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [Rp. 4000, Rp. 3000, Rp. 2000, Rp. 5000],
      backgroundColor: ['#007bff', '#dc3545', '#ffc107', '#28a745'],
    }],
  },       
});
```

do you guys have any idea ? any help will be appreciated

### Update #1

Hi I already tried your code before, i realized i used v2.8.0, when i used your code and change it into "Tooltips" and it run just like in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMbv3.png)

Here is my Updated code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Makassar", "Sinjae", "Bulukumba", "Gowa"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data:[4000, 3000, 2000, 5000],
      backgroundColor: ['#007bff', '#dc3545', '#ffc107', '#28a745'],
    }],
  },
   options:{
        tooltips:{
          callbacks:{
            label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.label}: Rp. ${ttItem.parsed}`)
          }
        }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a custom tooltip callback like this:

```
  options: {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
            label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.label}: Rp. ${ttItem.parsed}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

V2:

```
  options: {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
        label: (ttItem, items) => (`${items.labels[ttItem.index]}: R. ${items.datasets[ttItem.datasetIndex].data[ttItem.index]}`)
      }
    }
  }
```

Example V3:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => (`${ttItem.label}: Rp. ${ttItem.parsed}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Example V2:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (ttItem, items) => (`${items.labels[ttItem.index]}: R. ${items.datasets[ttItem.datasetIndex].data[ttItem.index]}`)
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried using your code, it didn't work, but i used this version chart.js 2.8.0, is it different languange?

Comment: @BrianThomas Updated answer for you to also incluse v2 syntax